# Correct http response to video stream

Tags: http, video, streaming

I'm currently developing my own little http server for video streaming, and i can't for the life of me figure out how this actually works...

This is the request i get from the client:

> "GET / HTTP/1.1
>   Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
>   Accept: */*
>   User-Agent: QuickTime.7.6.6 (qtver=7.6.6;cpu=IA32;os=Mac 10.6.4)
>   Connection: close

"

To which my http server responds(actual code):

> response << "HTTP / 1.1 200 OK" << "\r\n"
>                << "Accept-Ranges: bytes" << "\r\n"
>                << "Connection: close" << "\r\n"
>                << "Content-Type: video/x-msvideo" << "\r\n"
>                << "\r\n";

followed by the actual video as a bytearray.

The video doesnt play... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Two debugging suggestions:

Telnet directly to your webserver (e.g. `telnet 127.0.0.1 8080`) and type in the get request manually. Verify that the response you receive back are like you expect. This might cause your terminal settings/display in the window you run telnet to be messed up, but it is a very quick and simple test.

You can also capture the traffic with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).